# Code-splitting separate exports from a package to different bundles

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, gatsby, tree-shaking

I have a Gatsby site that consumes a number of packages. One of those packages is published from our monorepo: `@example/forms`. That package contains a number of named exports, one for each form component that we use on our site. There are quite a large number of forms and some are relatively complex multistep forms of a non-trivial size.

Currently, Gatsby/Webpack does a good job of treeshaking, and does produce a large number of bundles, some common bundles and one for each page of the site, containing any local assets or components that are only used on that page. However, all the components from `@example/forms` are being added to the `commons` bundle, despite the fact that most are used on only a single page. This is causing unnecessary bloat of the `commons` bundle which is loaded on every page.

If feels like it should be possible for the individual components within `@example/forms` to be split out into the page-specific bundles, but I'm not sure if I'm hoping for too much. For example, if Form A is only used on page 4, I'd like Form A to only be added to the bundle for page 4.

**Is this something that is supported, and if so, what could be preventing this from happening.**

`@example/forms` is transpiled with ES6 exports left intact, and `sideEffects` is set to `false` in its `package.json`.

Its `main` file is `index.js` which (re)exports all the form components from their own files as separate named exports:

```
export {default as FormA} from './forms/formA'
export {default as FormB} from './forms/formB'
...
```

Another thing that might be relevant is that all the exports from `@example/forms` *are* used within the Gatsby site, just on separate pages. It appears that perhaps tree-shaking cannot be used across bundles, i.e. tree shaking is performed first, then what is left is split into bundles. Using that logic, `@example/forms` would have been used on multiple pages and would be moved to commons. However this is definitely not optimal, and hopefully isn't what is happening.

Comment: It is possible to split function / component into a specific chunk, but what is your desired result? I know how to make it manually, is it OK by u?

Comment: You can also use [dynamic imports](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import) and [`React.lazy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) to have your forms lazy loading and of course packed to their own bundle. Check React [Code-Splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tree-shaking process is part of the minification step which is really at  late stage, since that it is not possible to reverse the order, first tree-shake then chunk split.

But you can split your forms lib before hand using some heuristics

1. The basic one is to use `splitChunks` in order to split this `@example/forms` module into a separate chunk as whole, this will decrease the commons bloat & on the first form usage all forms will be loaded.

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  ...
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        formComponents: {
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
          minChunks: 1,
          name: 'form-components',
          priority: 10,
          test: /[\\\/]node_modules[\\\/]@example[\\\/]forms[\\\/]/,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  ...
};
```

2. Make a chunk for each form inside the `@example/forms` module based on some heuristics, in my example I'm "grouping" all items based on the form path.

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  ...
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        formComponents: {
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 1,
          name(module) {
            const libPath = path.resolve(path.join('node_modules/@example/forms'))
            const folderBasedChunk = path.relative(libPath, module.context);
            const hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
            hash.update(folderBasedChunk)
            return hash.digest('hex').substring(0, 8)
          },
          priority: 10,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
          enforce: true,
          test: /[\\\/]node_modules[\\\/]@example[\\\/]forms[\\\/]src[\\\/]forms[\\\/]/,
        },
      },
    },
  ...
};
```

You can checkout a small example that I've created that mimics the scenario.
https://github.com/felixmosh/webpack-module-split-example

Hope this helps

Comment: Does this answer helped you?